# How Autofilter works?

Tags: vba

I got the following code,

```
Set V_RangeNamePlus = Range(V_RangeNameTop, LastRowFilter1)
V_RangeNamePlus.AutoFilter

ws1.Range(V_RangeNameTop, LastRowFilter1).AutoFilter Field:=LcolNRPlus, Criteria1:=""
ws1.Range(V_RangeNameTop, LastRowFilter1).AutoFilter Field:=FirsWhiteColNr, Criteria1:="<>"

V_RangeNameWhite.Resize(V_RangeNamePlus.Rows.Count-1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.ClearContents

V_RangeNamePlus.AutoFilter
```

My question is regarding the case when the Criteria 1 & 2 are not available for selection at all or just one of them, what this line of code does, or how the autofilter works in these case

```
V_RangeNameWhite.Resize(V_RangeNamePlus.Rows.Count-1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.ClearContents
```

Comment: It will throw an error - this is always the case when using `SpecialCells` and the result is empty. This is one of the rare cases where I use `On error resume next      'in case there is no result`. Don't forget to put `on error goto 0` after the `SpecialCells` row.

Comment: and a way to bypass the errors, what should I do to the code?

Comment: see answer below

Comment: What do you try accomplishing? The mentioned line resizes the initial (filtered) to keep all the range, except its last row. Of course, supposing that there are visible cells in the range, as stated above. But, do you really want clearing the content of the first row (which may be the header)? if you want clearing of the filtered range, except the header, you should use `V_RangeNameWhite.Resize(V_RangeNamePlus.Rows.Count-1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.ClearContents `...

Comment: I just wanted to update my code in case some errors occur, due to the mentioned case,  your line of code is right in general, but even my code as V_RangeNameWhite is a range without headers, while V_RangeNamePlus includes the headers, Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `on error resume next` like this

```vb
On error resume next    'in case there are no visible rows

V_RangeNameWhite.Resize(V_RangeNamePlus.Rows.Count-1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.ClearContents

On error goto 0
```

The perfect solution would be

```
Dim rgVisibleRows As Range

On Error Resume Next    'in case there are no visible Rows.
Set rgVisibleRows = V_RangeNameWhite.Resize(V_RangeNamePlus.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rgVisibleRows Is Nothing Then
    rgVisibleRows.Rows.ClearContents
End If
```

as in the previous solution the error could also result from clearing the contents.